# When does a Select operation in a Linq query become a Projection Operation?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, linq, iqueryable

I am a little confused , what are the projection operations in Linq queries? 
When does a Select operation in a Linq query become a Projection Operation? 
Can someone please enlighten me?

Comment: The immediate return value is an object that stores all the information that is required to perform the action. The query represented by this method is not executed until the object is enumerated either by calling its GetEnumerator method directly or by using foreach in Visual C# or For Each in Visual Basic. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the select clause produces something other than a copy of the source element, the operation is called a projection.

something like this is called a projection operation

```
var innerJoinQuery =
    from cust in customers
    join dist in distributors on cust.City equals dist.City
    select new { CustomerName = cust.Name, DistributorName = dist.Name };
```